# What's happening with EBS Volume when an EC2 instance is terminated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

When I terminated an EC2 instance, I thought the EC2 instance would be terminated after additional EBS Volume (not root volume) was detached.

However, even if I look up Cloudtrail, I couldn't find the event named `DetachVolume`.

When I terminate an EC2 instance, does EBS do something like disconnection without being detached?

**What's happening with EBS Volume when an EC2 instance is terminated?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an AWS EC2 instance is terminated, the AWS EBS volume attached to it either gets detached and deleted or just gets detached and doesn't get deleted. That depends on the value of the attribute named `Delete on termination` of the attached AWS EBS volume. You can see this on the AWS EC2 console by selecting the AWS EC2 instance and then navigating to the storage tab.

By default, its value is `True` for the root volume and `False` for the other volumes.

You can modify this value using AWS CLI only. From the AWS EC2 console, you can set its value when launching a new instance only. For already running AWS EC2 instance, use AWS CLI.

Examples using AWS CLI are below:

- Using a `.json` file: `aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id i-a3ef245 --block-device-mappings /path/to/file.json`

  - `.json` file format:

  ```
  [
    {
    "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
    "Ebs": {
      "DeleteOnTermination": false
      }
    }
  ]
  ```
- Using a `.json` object inline: `aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id i-a3ef245 --block-device-mappings "[{\"DeviceName\": \"/dev/sda\",\"Ebs\":{\"DeleteOnTermination\":false}}]"`

For more information, check this out: [How can I prevent my Amazon EBS volumes from being deleted when I terminate Amazon EC2 instances?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/deleteontermination-ebs/)

Comment: Does it mean that the event named terminate-instances contains the event named detach-volume. ?

Comment: @yan yes but it is only useful if  `Delete on termination` is set to `false`. Otherwise, it will directly delete the volume.

Comment: I understood how it works.  I want to use Eventbridge to trigger detach-volume. In the case of terminate-instance, detach-volume cannot be detected through cloudtrail, so should I create a new Eventbridge rule triggered by terminate-instance?

Comment: @yan, You can create a new EventBridge rule to be triggered upon terminate-instance to trigger an AWS Lambda function that will run detach-volume on it but that won't be useful if `Delete on termination` is set to `true` and also it is unnecessary as it is can be handled by AWS itself by just setting it to `false`. You should not add an overhead.

Comment: @yan My recommendation is to simply modify the value of the `Delete on termination` attribute to `false` and it will be detached upon termination automatically without deletion.

Comment: @yan My pleasure. :)

Answer (score 2):

When an instance terminates, the value of the DeleteOnTermination attribute for each attached EBS volume determines whether to preserve or delete the volume. By default, the DeleteOnTermination attribute is set to **True** for the root volume, and is set to **False** for all other volume types.

1. Delete on termination - false
   Volume ID   Device name  Size Status   Encrypt KMS ID Delete on Termination
   vol-09***   /dev/xvda   8    Attached  No       –       Yes

   vol-03**    /dev/sdb    8    Attached  No       –       No

Status after termination of instance :  Available

2. Delete on Termination - True

   Volume ID   Device name  Size Status   Encrypt KMS ID Delete on Termination

   vol-09*** /dev/xvda   8    Attached  No       –       Yes

   vol-03**    /dev/sdb    8    Attached  No       –       Yes

Status of EBS vol. apart from Root volume after termination of instance :  deleted